# Why GETPIVOTDATA() formula's parameter pivot_table can accept any cell reference or range that contains pivot table data and also filters for it?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

In MS Excel 2016, GETPIVOTDATA() formula's parameter pivot_table can accept any cell reference or range that contains pivot table data and also filters for it. Moreover, that parameter also accepts cell reference of one cell above the pivot table's location cell.

Like if you make any pivot table with some filters in excel and then use GETPIVOTDATA() formula, in which if you put cell reference of the cell just above the pivot table's location cell which is not inside the pivot table or related to it, even then the result for GETPIVOTDATA is calculated. Suppose, pivot table's location is B45 but you use B44 in the formula which is an empty cell. You can also use cell reference of any cell which are used for displaying the filters above the pivot table (usually there is one line gap between pivot table and it's filters). So, why that cell reference works which is not inside pivot table?

Comment: a) That is a bug b) That is some special handling for some edge cases. We won't know. It is weird though because `GETPIVOTDATA` manages to find the pivot table even if the cell right above belongs to some other object, e.g. a `List` that touches the pivot table.

Comment: If you add a filter to a pivottable, then it‘s placed above it and the row between also belongs to the table. As the mentioned parameter is only used to reference the (whole) table as such, I don‘t care :)

Comment: @Asger You are right but why that one cell (just above the pivot table's location cell) of the row between filters and pivot table is usable in GETPIVOTDATA. If I click on that cell, it doesn't appear as a part of table otherwise we get pivot table tools in menu bar.